# Routing error on rails button_to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to create a `button_to` that updates a single attribute, but I'm getting routing errors. Here's the code:

```
<%= button_to 'update', :action => 'update', :controller => 'users', :form => {:user => current_user, :share_articles_on_facebook => true} %>
```

And the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users", :form=>{:user=>#<User id: 3, ema....
```

Adding an explicit `:method` didn't fix the problem. Here are the routes:

```
    users GET    /users(.:format)    {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
          POST   /users(.:format)        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)    {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)    {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, simple mistake. It wanted an `:id` element, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've run into a similar problem. For me, I changed `button_to` to `link_to`. As far as I know, I was unable to get actions to work through buttons. I just made a link and styled it as a button.